# PowerShell FileSystemWatcher Move-Item cmdlet cannot take variable as destination

Tags: powershell, filesystemwatcher

I stumbled a very weird issue when trying to play around with FileSystemWatcher to monitor file changes in a specific folder. So, first things first, I created the FileSystemWatcher object by doing this:

```
$PathToMonitor = "C:\[some path]"
$FileSystemWatcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$FileSystemWatcher.Path  = $PathToMonitor
$FileSystemWatcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true

# make sure the watcher emits events
$FileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true
```

and then of course we need to register an event object with the FileSystemWatcher object as input object:

```
$destinationPath = "C:\[somepath]"
$handlers = Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $fileSystemWatch -EventName Changed -SourceIdentifier FileChanged -Action {

    $filePath = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
    $name = $Event.SourceEventArgs.Name 
    $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
    $timeStamp = $Event.TimeGenerated

    Move-Item -Path $filePath -Destination $destinationPath -Force
}
```

The problem here is with the $destinationPath. For some reason, if I specify the destination as a variable (just like what I did above with $destinationPath), the `Move-Item` command won't work and the `$handlers` event subscriber will stop working.

However, if I specify the destination path as a literal full path like so:

```
Move-Item -Path $path -Destination "C:\[SomePath]" -Force
```

then everything works as expected and the `$handlers` event subscriber doesn't stop working. Now, everytime a file in `$PathtoMonitor` is updated/changed, that file will be moved to `C:\[SomePath]` automatically and the handler doesn't stop working.

The really weird thing is, if I put

```
Move-Item -Path $path -Destination $destinationPath -Force
```

somewhere else outside of the `$handlers` Action script block, then the file which I want to move is transferred to `$destinationPath` just fine.

Does anyone have any idea on why this is happening? I mean..., it's okay because I can just specify the full folder path in the `Move-Item` command but this is really bugging me because I couldn't find any reason why replacing that full path with a variable wouldn't work.